# Returning IHttpActionResult instead of just custom json object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("searchparts")]
    public IHttpActionResult SearchResults([FromUri] PartsQuery query)
    {
        try
        {
            //Model Validation is done using ValidateActionFilter
            SearchResults data = DataHelpers.ConvertSearchResults(_search.RelatedPartNumber(query.PartFamily, query.AdditionalKeywords, query.MaxCount));
            if (data == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("An error occured while processing the request. Null values were returned.");
            }
            else
            {
                return Ok<SearchResults>(data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

So This is sample Web API 2 code. I would like to return IHttpActionResult which will include Http Status, but all I am getting is json response of SearchResults. How do I change this code to get Http info included in the response. All the examples I looked up basically said return Ok(data) would work.What am I missing here?

Comment: Each one of those are derived from `IHttpActionResult`. ApiController has methods that return a desired status. As you have already discovered, `Ok()`, `Ok(object model)`, `BadRequest`...etc will return a response with the desired status code. Are you looking for a specific status code in particular

Comment: @Nkosi I would like the status code to be a part of response received in the json object. May be my assumption was that Ok, 200 would be a part of the response seen by the user and not just received by the browser/ HttpClient/ <whatever client they use>.

Comment: Why would you want to include the response status code in the response body?